# Keep getting an invalid syntax error with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I don't understand what I have done wrong in this code (I am starting a GUI)

```
from Tkinter import *


def dn():
    print("Do nothing")

root = Tk()

menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

subm= Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=subm)
subm.add_command(label="New...", command=dn)
subm.add_command(label="Save!", command=dn)
subm.add_separator()
subm.add_command(label="Exit!", command=dn)

editmenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editmenu)
editmenu.add_command(label="Undo", command=dn

root.mainloop()
```

It tells me that root from

```
root.mainloop()
```

is invalid and i don't understand why?

Comment: can you post the traceback??

Comment: you must close `()` i.e `editmenu.add_command(label="Undo", command=dn)`

Comment: In all seriousness, who on earth is upvoting a typo?!

Comment: Not sure... but hey free reputation points.

Answer (score 6):

You have a missing bracket on the line:

```
editmenu.add_command(label="Undo", command=dn)
```

Comment: Thankyou I completely missed that

Comment: No worries, it happens :)